# Apply GPUImage filter to part of video

Tags: ios, swift, gpuimage

I want to add two filters to one video, so half of the screen shows one filter and the other half another filter. But they should be applied to the same video, just on different parts of the screen.

Is it possible to do with GPUImage? If not, what are the alternatives?

[image]

Comment: I did what I wanted to do, but it was kinda hacky. If you want to create an illusion that a filter is applied to only a part of a video, just stack two render views on top of each other and synchronize the video. Then apply a mask to the upper view to make it transparent. It will create an illusion that the video has two different filters applied to it.

Answer (score 2):

While still a little experimental, [the Swift version of GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage2) has a new capability for masking filter operations on images.

Most filters (but not all at present) can use the `mask` property to provide an image for masking the regions of the image you want to apply a filter to. The mask image uses the alpha channel to denote the regions you want to mask off, with opaque areas being filtered and transparent ones unfiltered.

Comment: Hey, i'm trying to do this with GPUImage2 but I'm not totally sure I'm doing the right thing. I have images (in PNG format) and am creating a PictureInput object (which conforms to ImageSource) with them applying that to the mask property but it's not taking effect. Any pointers?

Comment: @Cocoadelica - It might be best to ask that as a new question, with the code describing your setup.

Comment: I fixed it! Always the way right after posting here... need to call processImage()